# Why is NT Kernel Logger already running?

Tags: windows-8.1, performance-monitor

I'm using Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit. Since some time ago, I started to find a "NT Kernel Logger" in "Performance Monitor" --> "Data Collector Sets" --> "Event Trace Sessions", and it's automatically started at boot time. I don't know what's causing that. If I look at another Windows 8.1 Professional computer, it's not there.

The result is that I can't use the NT Kernel event trace data collector in my data collector sets. Any data collector set that uses the NT Kernel event trace data collector (e.g. a data collector set created out of the "System Performance" template) would fail to start automatically.

How do I find out what is causing the NT Kernel Logger to be automatically started? And how do I fix that? I have tried stopping and removing it from "Data Collector Sets" --> "Event Trace Sessions", but it comes right back after reboot.

Comment: install the WPT (part of the Windows 8.1 SDK) and run **xperf -stop**. Does it now come back after a reboot.

Comment: @magicandre1981 `xperf -stop` stopped and removed "NT Kernel Logger" *temporarily*. It came back after a reboot. However, I think I now have some clue of what is starting it. It appears to be Intel's DiskTrace thing, which is not present on the other machine I checked. It may have been installed as part of some Intel SDK or driver update. Now I need to figure out whether it's safe to uninstall.

Comment: NT Kernel Logger captures Kernel data (CPU, disk). But Win8 supports more than 1 kernel logger, so other tools (ProcessExplorer, WPRUI) still work.

Comment: I dug around a bit more. It seems that some Intel driver or SDK installed a few new services a few weeks ago: "Energy Server Service WILLAMETTE", "Intel(R) System Usage Report Service SystemUsageReportSvc_WILLAMETTE", and "User Energy Server Service WILLAMETTE". Those were interfering with my Data Collector Set. Even after executing `xperf -stop` and seeing "NT Kernel Logger" disappear temporarily, I couldn't start my Data Collector Set. But as soon as I disabled the new services, my Data Collector Set worked again.

Comment: ok. Post your finding as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question (partially):

It seems that some Intel driver or SDK installed a few new services a few weeks ago:

- Energy Server Service WILLAMETTE
- Intel(R) System Usage Report Service SystemUsageReportSvc_WILLAMETTE
- User Energy Server Service WILLAMETTE

These were interfering with my Data Collector Set.

Even after executing `xperf -stop` and seeing "NT Kernel Logger" disappear temporarily, I couldn't start my Data Collector Set.

As soon as I disabled the new services, my Data Collector Set worked again.

Unfortunately, it is still unclear *how* these services prevent my Data Collector Set from starting. Performance Monitor gives these really vague error messages. It can't tell me what dependency is in use and by what process.

There is also absolutely no documentation about these services on Intel's official website.

**UPDATE**

I am now certain that the services get installed with "Intel Driver Update Utility", when you agree to join the customer experience improvement program.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm, same problem here - did you ever figure out what caused these services to become installed?

Comment: @EamonNerbonne See my updated answer.

Comment: Stopping Intel(R) System Usage Report Service was enough for me. `sc stop SystemUsageReportSvc_WILLAMETTE` under admin console

Comment: They also get installed (in version 2.6 of the Driver Update Utility) if you **decline** to join the customer experience improvement program, which I find to be very irritating.