# Stop NT Kernel Logger

Tags: windows-7, logging, kernel, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2015's Concurrency Visualizer on Windows 7 (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Diagnostics.ConcurrencyVisualizerforVisualStudio2015).

When I try to run it, I get an error "The concurrency visualizer cannot start because etw collection is currently in progress"

Looking around online, it seems that if the NR Kernel Logger process is already running, then it interferes with the event collection required for the Concurrency Visualizer.

So, I ran Performance Monitor, selected `Data Collector Sets > Event Trace Sessions > NR Kernel Logger`; stopped it; and it just started up again.

I also tried `xperf -stop`, `logman stop "NT Kernel Logger" -ets` `tracelog -stop "NT Kernel Logger"`and `tracelog -remove GlobalLogger`; all with the same result that it didn't stop / stay stopped.

Any ideas how to stop it?

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1011435/why-is-nt-kernel-logger-already-running).

Comment: Thanks, I saw that - I don't have that service installed that I can see.